# Tweening effect for scrolling list in AS3 Flex

Tags: list, actionscript-3, apache-flex, scroll, tween

I have a canvas called `tileListCanvas` which I scroll through vertically when the mouse moves up and down over the `tileListCanvas`. Everything is working fine but I would like to add a tween effect to the scrolling behaviour so that scrolling slows down gradually and comes to a stop when the user stops moving the mouse. The scrolling behavior is implemented by

```
target = tileListCanvas.verticalScrollPosition -= (10 - yDiff)
```

for scrolling up and

```
target = tileListCanvas.verticalScrollPosition += (10 + yDiff)
```

for scrolling down.

If anyone can give me some idea of how this can be done it would make my day!

```
[Bindable]private var previousX:Number = 0;
[Bindable]private var previousY:Number = 0;
[Bindable]private var currentX:Number = 0;
[Bindable]private var currentY:Number = 0;
[Bindable]private var xDir:String;
[Bindable]private var yDir:String;
[Bindable]private var xDiff:Number = 0;
[Bindable]private var yDiff:Number = 0;

[Bindable]private var lastX:Number = 0;
[Bindable]private var lastY:Number = 0;
[Bindable]private var speed:Number;
[Bindable]private var target:Number = 0;

private function initMouseDirectionChecker():void
{
    tileList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, checkDirection);
}

private function beginScrolling(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void
{
    tileListCanvas.verticalScrollPosition -= 5;
}

 public function checkDirection(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    getHorizontalDirection();
    getVerticalDirection();

    dir1.text = "x: " + xDir
    dir2.text = "y: " + yDir;
}

//Horizontal
private function getHorizontalDirection():void
{
    previousX = currentX; //Checks the last position
    currentX = stage.mouseX; //Gets the current position

    if (previousX > currentX) //Compares both positions to determine the direction
    {
        xDir = "left";
    }
    else if (previousX < currentX)
    {
        xDir = "right";
    }
    else
    {
        xDir = "none";
    }
}

//Vertical
private function getVerticalDirection():void
{
    previousY = currentY; //Checks the last position
    currentY = stage.mouseY; //Gets the current position

    if (previousY > currentY) //Compares both positions to determine the direction
    {
        yDir = "up";
        target = tileListCanvas.verticalScrollPosition -= (10 - yDiff);                    
    }
    else if (previousY < currentY)
    {
        yDir = "down";
        target = tileListCanvas.verticalScrollPosition += (10 + yDiff);
    }
    else
    {
        yDir = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: TweenLite is the easiest way to do what you want: https://greensock.com/getting-started-as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks the swift reply much appreciated!

I followed your advise and downloaded GASP from [greensock.com](http://www.greensock.com) where I was able to import the greensock swc into my project and access TweenLite. I used the code below to achieve the scrolling effect I wanted.

```
TweenLite.to(tileListCanvas, 2, {verticalScrollPosition:currentY +10, ease:Back.easeOut});
```

Hope this can help others out.